# how to restrict shuffling while user presses the refresh button

Tags: javascript, arrays, shuffle

When the user presses the button and gets the first shuffle, I want the first result being shown again if there are further shuffle attempts.

For example: 
first time shuffle [42, 37, 11, 2];
further shuffles:[42, 37, 11, 2] (if the user the presses the refresh button i want to show the same first shuffle result again9

```
<script>
    var arr = [2, 11, 37, 42];
    arr = shuffle(arr);
    console.log(arr);

    function shuffle(array) {
      var currentIndex = array.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex;

      // While there remain elements to shuffle...
      while (0 !== currentIndex) {
        // Pick a remaining element...
        randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
        currentIndex -= 1;
        // And swap it with the current element.
        temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
        array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
        array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
      }        
      return array;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do a variation of what is called memoization. In this case, we just want to ensure we only evaluate the shuffle once. So first time through we shuffle and then store the result (cache). Next time it is called it will simply return the cache.

This works fine as long as you don't apply this routine to another function as well since it will only hold one cached value. There are ways to make this more generic, and you could start by reading up on this approach at [this link](http://inlehmansterms.net/2015/03/01/javascript-memoization/)

```js
function memoize(func) {
  var cache;
  return function() {
    if(cache) {
      return cache;
    }
    else {
      var val = func.apply(this, arguments);
      cache = val;
      return val;
    }
  };
}

var shuffle = memoize(function (array) {

  var currentIndex = array.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex;

  // While there remain elements to shuffle...
  while (0 !== currentIndex) {

    // Pick a remaining element...
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex -= 1;

    // And swap it with the current element.
    temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
    array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
    array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
  }

  return array;
});

var arr = [2, 11, 37, 42];
arr = shuffle(arr);
console.log(arr);
arr = shuffle(arr);
console.log(arr);
arr = shuffle(arr);
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the result in `sessionStorage`; when you load, only shuffle if you can't get it from `sessionStorage`. Something like:

```
var arr, arrJSON;
arrJSON = sessionStorage.getItem('shuffledArray');
if (arrJSON) {
  arr = JSON.parse(arrJSON);
} else {
  arr = shuffle([2, 11, 37, 42)];
  sessionStorage.setItem('shuffledArray', JSON.stringify(arr));
}
```